# Collection not updating upon saving opposite entity using Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, persistence

I have two entities that are in a one-to-many relationship:

Parent entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
public List<Child> getChildren()
```

Child entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
public Parent getParent()
```

Consider the following code (inside transaction):

```
Child child = childRepository.findById(id).get();
Parent parent = child.getParent();
child.setParent(null);
childRepository.saveAndFlush(child);
List<Child> children = parent.getChildren();
```

In this case the 'children' list will still contain the child entity although it is already removed. I tried flushing the repositories, saving the parent entity or even getting a new one from the parentRepository, none of these worked.

Why is the children list not updated upon save and how can I make sure the collection is up-to-date without explicitly removing the entity (I want to make further operations on the entities in the collection)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to map a @OneToMany association is to rely on the @ManyToOne side to propagate all entity state changes: Bidirectional @OneToMany.

So in your case, the parent should be shown as below

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public List<Child> getChildren();
```

Then you have to add the following methods

```
public void addChild(Child c){
   c.setParent(this);
   children.add(c);
}
public void removeChild(Child c){
   c.setParent(this);
   children.remove(c);
}
```

Then in your transactional method call saveAndFlush using the parent repository.

```
parentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent)
```